# Free node memory and low PLE

Tags: sql-server-2014, memory, page-life-expectancy

We run a SQL Server 2014 standard edition on a 94 GB RAM server with 82 GB RAM dedicated to SQL.

I know PLE is not the answer to all and we should not focus on it too much. But if you look at the image below, on one of our nodes, the PLE is very low, and stays low too. But we also have A LOT of free memory on that node. This seems to be the case for us on most days.

I feel like free memory is wasted memory, is that a correct assumption?

Why doesn't SQL Server not utilize this memory to store data pages in and drop them when it needs the memory for other applications?

[image: Buffernode and memory counters]

Results

```
select * from sys.dm_os_process_memory
```

[image: dm_os_process_memory results]

```
select * from sys.dm_os_memory_nodes
```

[image: dm_os_memory_nodes]

```
select @@version
```

> Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-CU18) (KB4500180) - 12.0.5687.1 (X64)
> Jul 20 2019 21:27:07    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Standard
> Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3  (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)

```
exec sp_readerrorlog
```

[image: sp_readerrorlog]

```
select * from sys.dm_os_nodes
```

[image: sys.dm_os_nodes]

**Update on 2022/04/26**: We upgraded our SQL Server 2014 to SP3 CU 4 and for now, it seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Can you add the complete output of `select * from sys.dm_os_process_memory`  `select * from sys.dm_os_memory_nodes`and `select @@version` in the question. Please also add first 100 lines of `sp_readerrorlog` in the question

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I updated the question, I was unsure if you meant the actual first 100 lines of the error log or the last 100 lines so let me know if you need the last 100 lines.

Comment: Can you also add output of `select * from Sys.dm_os_nodes`. Its seems like one of the nodes is using more memory but let me check if there is *actually* NUMA configured physically or not

Comment: Ok, I updated the question

Comment: How big is the database itself?

Comment: The database is around 530 GB.

Answer (score 0):

Please dont treat this as answer, just trying to highlight few things.
As per the [Output of sys.dm_os_memory_nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZt7B.png)

I can see on both nodes VAS committed `virtual_address_space_committed_kb` is almost same 40 GB. But the reservation is significantly less on Node 1 which means SQL Server is not utilizing that node to its potential. Most of the workload is handled by Node 0. I have seen this in many NUMA nodes system but this is something either a bug or something relevant to how NUMA is configured. You have SP2 could you please move to SP3 CU 4 so that you are at least extended supported. may be, just may be this might resolve this behaviour.

Also note from output of `sys.dm_os_nodes` the `active_worker_count` is almost same. So SQL Server is reserving and committing more from Node 0. Really dont have idea why so may be a behaviour, may be a bug.

In such scenario since Node 1 is not loaded at all I would ignore PLE.

> NOTE: Currently SQL Server does not have Locked pages in memory
> enabled, please enable it, it would require restart and then see if
> the behavior changes.

**EDIT:**
Update from OP. Applying SQL Server 2014 to SP3 CU 4 seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Unsure if this is the case. Maybe I should have included this in my question. I am 100% sure (but can't show it now) that we have days that the pages in memory is more spread out over nodes, as in, A LOT on 1 node and way less, but still a lot in the other node. Think 4000 on node 00 and 16000 on node 01. On other days, the pages are all situated on the other node, see this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPTuj.png

Comment: @KPH. This is interesting, so this makes me believe what you are seeing is normal. SQL Server is internally deciding what node to use and send workloads to. One more Q did you played with CPU affinity mask ? for Node 1 its 240 which is nit odd

Comment: @KPH Can you go to your SQL Server, right click and select properties. Go to processor tab select it on left side and paste the screenshot. Make sure you expand all the + button and then paste the screenshot

Comment: I'd have to ask the external firm that helped set up the whole infrastructure. Internally, we have no idea who set this or why it was set to this. I will try to get this information as soon as possible.

Here are the processor properties.
https://imgur.com/a/u3mGCQG

Comment: I am not down to enable the Lock Pages In Memory settings. I had no idea what it is but after some Googling, it seems a bad idea if you run your SQL Server on a virtual machine.

Comment: No its not a bad idea, this is wrong info. In most cases its helpful. You have already left 12 GB for OS and assuming it is dedicated system you can enable it and MUST enable it so that no external thing can pull sql server memory and cause severe paging. You are using Hyper V so again you are on safe side.

Comment: Ok, we enabled the setting today and rebooted the server. So far, it seems to balance the pages more evenly. Anything I could monitor to find out what might cause this issue?

Comment: @KHP You just keep  using the queries to track NUMA memory allocation I have asked in chat, also keep looking at PLE  and free memory for both the NUMA nodes. Please plan for applying SP3 and then SP3 CU 4 later this is also very important.

Comment: So all was well and then a big query happened that cleared out most of the pages in memory and we are back to square one, except it is the other node now.
https://i.imgur.com/3i0DVBP.png

After reading the memorystatus results, it seems like it keeps a bunch of memory free for datapages, but never uses the space, is this a correct assumption?
https://i.imgur.com/2DCBnlL.png

I am planning on an upgrade as soon as possible, hopefully next weekend!

Comment: Did you face any issue performance wise, if not, it would be safe to assume this is how NUMA nodes work.

Comment: We do face performance issues but unsure if it is completely related to this. We have to manually update the statistics often and are trying to find out why that is.
I guess we will have to wait until the upgrade, I just find it very strange that the Optimizer keeps throwing out pages when there is such a huge amount of memory free. Surely, that must contribute to the performance hit. Once we have upgraded, I will monitor the situation, open a ticket with Microsoft if needed and keep you updated. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: So I monitored the situation more closely and it does throw out indexes that it would need because it is on one node and it keeps "less-used" indexes in memory on the other node. Any way to mitigate this issue, perhaps disable a node or some thing else? Is it a correct assumption that it will always try to save the same indexes to the same NUMA buffer pool, or should this more balanced? I am upgrading the sql server as we speak on our non-production environments, if all goes well, we upgrade this saturday.

Comment: We upgraded our SQL Server 2014 to SP3 CU 4 and for now, it seems to have resolved the issue. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Unbalanced "reserved" Virtual Memory pages is not an issue.  Only "committed" Virtual Memory is allocated and can be used.